# How to restrict Azure management portal access to corporate network(IP range) only

Tags: azure, azureportal

Is there any way we can restrict sign in to azure portal to Company network only. We dont want to give access over public internet

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do to block / allow IP addresses to the Azure portal - you don't own the portal; Microsoft does. And it's a multi-tenant portal.

Not sure *why* you want to block the portal, but I guess that doesn't matter...

You *can* block access to the apps you deploy, via inbound network rules, access control lists, etc.

The only thing you can do with the portal is grant specific user permissions (via role-based access control) on specific resources.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually client has requirement due to compliance reasons.

Comment: Azure AD conditional access now supports Azure Portal to restrict access. You can create policy and restrict the access to azure portal to specific IP